# Kernel Crash when using Fill function ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using `R 3.5.1` on a stand-alone environment and whenever I use the `fill` parameter in `ggplot`, the kernel crashes. When i remove the `fill` parameter, the plot works fine. This worked on an older set up (no specs available). I also tried just saving using `ggsave`, and I get the same error message.

**Error messgage when running in native `R`**

```
*** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x7f3019a29703, cause 'illegal operand'

Traceback:
 1: id(data[disc], drop = TRUE)
 2: add_group(evaled)
 3: f(..., self = self)
 4: l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 5: f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 6: by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot))
 7: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 8: ggplot_build(x)
 9: print.ggplot(x)
10: function (x, ...) UseMethod("print")(x)



SessionInfo:
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] stringr_1.4.0  reshape2_1.4.3 ggplot2_3.2.0  dplyr_0.8.1    tidyr_0.8.3
[6] DBI_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.1       withr_2.1.2      crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1
 [5] plyr_1.8.4       grid_3.5.1       R6_2.4.0         gtable_0.3.0
 [9] magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.4.2     stringi_1.2.4
[13] rlang_0.4.0      lazyeval_0.2.2   tools_3.5.1      glue_1.3.1
[17] purrr_0.3.2      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_3.5.1   pkgconfig_2.0.2
[21] colorspace_1.4-1 tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_2.1.3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducible example. Can you try updating `R` to `3.6.1`?

Comment: also: can you try it in a  clean environment, in a console (not RStudio, just in case - although maybe that's what you meant by "standalone environment" ...)

Comment: The error comes in from terminal R, not RStudio.

I reproduced the error using the Mtcars database, so I dont think its just an error with my code, but i will add monday. Trying to understand if there something in my installation or setup I should investigate.